# I need to drag an element from a list and drop it to another block in angular 6

Tags: angular5, ng2-dragula

I am working on drag and drop functionality(using [ng2-dragula](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula)).

I need to drag an element from a list and drop it to another blocks. But where I am stuck is that I need to drop only one element in the drop block at a time and if I remove firstly added element from drop block only then I can add another element. There are multiple drop blocks. But list block is one only.

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: I have does not implemented any code because I don't no how it is possible?

Answer (score -2):

I have created a stackblitz url: I think this is what you are looking for..

you can always catch events in ng2-dragula like this:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula';

export class MyComponent {
  // RxJS Subscription is an excellent API for managing many unsubscribe calls.
  // See note below about unsubscribing.
  subs = new Subscription();

  constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) {

    // These will get events limited to the VAMPIRES group.

    this.subs.add(this.dragulaService.drag("VAMPIRES")
      .subscribe(({ name, el, source }) => {
        // ...
      })
    );
    this.subs.add(this.dragulaService.drop("VAMPIRES")
      .subscribe(({ name, el, target, source, sibling }) => {
        // ...
      })
    );
    // some events have lots of properties, just pick the ones you need
    this.subs.add(this.dragulaService.dropModel("VAMPIRES")
      // WHOA
      // .subscribe(({ name, el, target, source, sibling, sourceModel, targetModel, item }) => {
      .subscribe(({ sourceModel, targetModel, item }) => {
        // ...
      })
    );

    // You can also get all events, not limited to a particular group
    this.subs.add(this.dragulaService.drop()
      .subscribe(({ name, el, target, source, sibling }) => {
        // ...
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // destroy all the subscriptions at once
    this.subs.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-dragula-base-jystom?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I have used an event to manipulate data like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  // these are some basics to get you started -- modify as you see fit.
subs = new Subscription();
  vamps = [
    { name: "Bad Vamp" },
    { name: "Petrovitch the Slain" },
    { name: "Bob of the Everglades" },
    { name: "The Optimistic Reaper" }
  ];

  vamps2 = [
    { name: "Dracula" },

  ];

  constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) {
    // use these if you want

    this.dragulaService.createGroup("VAMPIRES", {
      // ...
    });

    this.dragulaService.dropModel("VAMPIRES").subscribe(args => {
      console.log(args);
    });
      this.subs.add(this.dragulaService.drop("VAMPIRES")
      .subscribe(({ name, el, target, source, sibling }) => {
        this.vamps2=[{name: el.textContent}]
        // ...
              console.log( "@@@@@@@@@@@@@",name, el.textContent, target, source, sibling);

      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If vamps2 block drop the the vamp1 again, so  vamps2 block is not a empty. and also multiple vamps bloks, link vamps3 , vamp4 so on. So how it work?

Comment: I didn't get u...what do u want to achieve exactly?  Do u want left table not to be empty?? And for multiple block you just need to catch the drag and drop event in order to make your changes based on drag and drop.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21513699)

Comment: @U9-Forward @ WhatsThePoint The answer to this question can be best understood by code which i have done in this url i have provided and these url do not easily become unavailable..and as per the comment done by Ms. Arora ,My answer partially answers the question and for full answer I am asking for clearification on question as you can see..However I have edited the answer to clearify.

Comment: My requirement is :- 

I need to drag an element from a list and drop it to another (multiple) blocks. But Where I am struck is that I need to drop only one element in the drop block at a time and If I remove added element from drop block so then I can add another element. 

There are multiple drop blocks but drag block is only one.

Comment: @HarleenKaurArora This is the updated plunker solving the issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-dragula-base-jystom?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This code is not working version "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0". I have used angular 5 version.

Comment: @HarleenKaurArora you can use this link https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/blob/master/MIGRATION-v2.md to transform the code to 1.5.0